# Turning game - counting moves

Tags: combinatorics

Basic definitions/setup-
*a card can be placed on either the "Up" or "Down" position.
*The game is played until there are more down facing cards than up facing cards.
*we count the number of events or turns it takes to get to the ending state

Rules of the game

1. Initially choose n (>=1) number of cards to be placed up. No cards will start down.
2. If n is odd then add 3 faced up cards, if n is even then turn over half the cards to down.
3. Repeat step 2 until down > up

Now for my question:
I have been able to prove, I think, that it can take as few as 4 stages and at most 5 stages for an end state to be achieved. But the question I'm trying to answer is how can we group the numbers that require 4 stages from those that require 5? Like what composition must a number have that others don't to require 5 stages?

For those who care, this is not a homework question. It is just one that I made up and have been playing around with for awhile.

Comment: You seem to be counting positions including the first.  If we write $a/b$ for a position with $a$ cards up and $b$ cards down, for $n=1$ we do $1/0,4/0,2/2,1/3$ and are done.  Is that what you mean by $4$ stages?  Why doesn't $n=12$ go $12/0, 6/6, 3/9$ and end in $3$?

Comment: You are counting it correctly. And you are right about the 12 case. Looking back over my proof, I had listed the situation where 3 stages arrise but for some reason over looked it. So more precisely the stages seem to be bounded between 3 and 5.  But in thinking about this I think I see the solution to my own question finally

Comment: I dont have any great way to classify them beyond if: n, n/2 are both even then we have 3 stages and if n, (n+3)/2 are both odd then we have 5 stages

Comment: It only depends on the remainder when dividing n by 4. Write n=4k or n=4k+1 or n=4k+2 or n=4k+3. These four cases take 3, 4, 4, and 5 stages respectively.

Comment: You need two divisions by $2$ to get to the end.  This is what suggests working modulo $4$.  The question is how many odd numbers you hit before the second even.